# Building a FW image with coreboot & TianoCore fails with "ERROR: please_install uuid-dev"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firmware

I am trying to build a firmware image for Intel CPU motherboard using coreboot + TianoCore (I have not done that previously but I believe coreboot + TianoCore should be the right way to do it using open source tools). I am using Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS.

I am following the official coreboot tutorial: https://doc.coreboot.org/tutorial/part1.html

I have successfully built the coreinfo payload as given in the tutorial but when I try to build the TianoCore payload (at step 4), i get the following error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-System-Product-Name:~/coreboot$ make -C payloads/external/tianocore
make: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/coreboot/payloads/external/tianocore'
test -d /home/ubuntu/coreboot/payloads/external/tianocore/tianocore && (cd /home/ubuntu/coreboot/payloads/external/tianocore/tianocore; rm -rf Build; rm -f Conf/tools_def.txt) || exit 0
cd  /home/ubuntu/coreboot/payloads/external/tianocore/tianocore; \
    echo "    Fetching new commits from the Tianocore repo"; \
    git fetch --multiple origin upstream 2>/dev/null; \
    if ! git rev-parse --verify -q origin/uefipayload_202107 >/dev/null; then \
        echo "    origin/uefipayload_202107 is not a valid git reference"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
    if git status --ignore-submodules=dirty | grep -qv clean; then \
        echo "    Checking out Tianocore revision origin/uefipayload_202107"; \
        git checkout --detach origin/uefipayload_202107; \
    else \
        echo "    Working directory not clean; will not overwrite"; \
    fi; \
    git submodule update --init
    Fetching new commits from the Tianocore repo
Fetching origin
Fetching upstream
    Checking out Tianocore revision origin/uefipayload_202107
HEAD is now at f7fe27d... Add build option to disable Above 4G Decode
echo "Checking uuid-dev..."
Checking uuid-dev...
echo "#include <uuid/uuid.h>" > libtest.c
echo "int main(int argc, char **argv) { (void) argc; (void) argv; return 0; }" >> libtest.c
libtest.c -o libtest >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo " found uuid-dev." || \
    ( echo " Not found."; echo "ERROR: please_install uuid-dev (libuuid-devel)"; exit 1 )
 Not found.
ERROR: please_install uuid-dev (libuuid-devel)
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'checktools' failed
make: *** [checktools] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/coreboot/payloads/external/tianocore'
```

It says the uuid-dev is not installed. But I have already installed uuid-dev using `sudo apt-get install uuid-dev`, as shown below:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-System-Product-Name:~/coreboot$ apt-cache search libuuid
libuuid-perl - Perl extension for using UUID interfaces as defined in e2fsprogs
libuuid1 - Universally Unique ID library
uuid-dev - Universally Unique ID library - headers and static libraries
uuid-runtime - runtime components for the Universally Unique ID library
libdata-uuid-libuuid-perl - uuid.h based UUID generation module
libuuid-tiny-perl - pure Perl module to generate v1, v3, v4, and v5 UUIDs
libuuidm-ocaml-dev - Universally unique identifiers for OCaml
php-uuid - PHP UUID extension
```

It confirms that uuid-dev has been installed, and I have tried reinstalling it with different flags, upgrades etc. several times but the error does not go away. This error is already observed by https://www.reddit.com/r/coreboot/comments/kigu2z/uuiddev_libuuiddev_tianocore/ but there is no answer on how to remove the error.

So how can I resolve this error?

Update:

A) Running the `dpkg -s uuid-dev` returns the following status Package:

```
uuid-dev Status: install ok installed
```

B) Running the `apt list --installed` returns the following status:

```
uuid-dev/xenial-updates,now 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.10 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: `apt-cache search` doesn't tell you what's installed on your system, it's used to [search for packages in repos](https://linuxhint.com/apt_cache_search_packages/). The commands to list installed packages are [`apt list --installed` and `dpkg -l`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages).

Comment: Check installed : `dpkg -s uuid-dev` . ..... and the file list `dpkg -L uuid-dev`

Comment: @KnudLarsen  Running the `dpkg -s uuid-dev` returns the following status 

```Package: uuid-dev
Status: install ok installed
```

Comment: @Peregrino69 running the `apt list --installed` returns the following status:  ```uuid-dev/xenial-updates,now 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.10 amd64 [installed]```

Comment: @Sig123456 Please don't answer in comments, but update your question with new / updated info. That way the relevant details are available for anyone who wants to pitch in without the need of digging them up from comments. I would edit the question replacing the non-applicable `apt-cache search` result with the applicable `apt list-installed` -result.